# Python 3: module in same directory as script: "ImportError: No module named"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to import a module (`venues`) from an IPython shell. The `venues` module is correctly imported but it then tries itself to import a module named `makesoup` and fails to do so.

I'm located in the `~` directory and am trying to import the `venues.py` file located in the subdirectory `processors`. The `makesoup.py`file is also located in the `processors` subdirectory, which means any Python script near it should be able to find it, right?

```
In [1]: import processors.venues
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-765135ed9288> in <module>()
----> 1 import processors.venues

~/processors/venues.py in <module>()
      7 """
      8 
----> 9 import makesoup
     10 import re
     11 

ImportError: No module named 'makesoup'
```

I have added an empty `__init__.py` in *both* the `~` and `processors` directories, unsuccessfully.

Note: the `makesoup` module is correctly imported when I'm located in `processors` but I know this is not the only way it should work.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> The `makesoup.py` file is also located in the `processors` subdirectory, which means any Python script near it should be able to find it, right?

No.  This feature [was changed in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) and that syntax no longer works.

Change the `import makesoup` to this:

```
from . import makesoup
```

Or to this:

```
from processors import makesoup
```

Both of these will make it impossible to run `python processors/venues.py` directly, though you can still do `python -m processors.venues` from your home directory.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. However, I don't understand why these solutions would make it impossible to run `venues.py`directly. Can you tell me why?

Comment: If you use an explicit relative import (the first option I listed), the `__package__` magic variable must be set, but `python` won't do this when running a script directly without `-m`.  If you use an absolute import, Python probably won't be able to find the `processors` package, since it is not in the same directory as the script.  Again, `-m` will fix this.

Comment: I also didn't realize this change when moving to Python 3. If you only want to import a function in a file try this `from .makesoup import this_function`

Comment: The answer should be edited with @blaylockbk comment. Worked for me

Comment: Just a small note, if you just wanted to import a single symbol from `makesoup`, you can use:
`from .makesoup import symbol_from_makesoup`

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, this does not work:

```
from . import xxx
```

Maybe someone will tell you to add **init**.py under the directory. It won't work for some special cases as well.

The most useful way would be to check the sys.path first with:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Then you can find where you should import from.

There is an another way as well:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname("__file__"), '..')))
```

or use **insert** function instead:

```
sys.path.insert(0, xxx)
```

These two ways are suitable for small project. I will recommend you choose the first one if your project is complex and huge.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, I had the same issue and I can confirm that the following works if the mymodule file is in the same directory.

```
from . import mymodule
```

I'm using Python3.10.11 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (if that helps)